# VBA - System generated report amendments

Tags: excel, report, vba

I am having some issues in creating a macro that will amend a system generated report.

I would like to be able to paste my system generated report into excel and through pushing a button (macro) that it will select every other line of my data and copy the figures to another tab, I would then like it to delete these alternate rows.

Then it would go to the other tab and lift these figures and paste them into the outside column.

I have tried doing this through recording a macro but I'm not sure how to get it to select a varying range of data.

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Paula

Comment: What is the purpose of this, are they duplicates?

Comment: No they're not duplicates the system I am running the inital report from puts the number of hits on one line and the total number underneath however I am being asked to provide it in a side by side format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should meet your needs. It checks if the first row in your range is odd or even, which determines into which column it moves (the first row in a "series", which has the value, moves to the first column, and the second, with totals, moves to the second column).

Let me know if it helps.

```
Sub MoveAlternatingToNewTab()
    Dim wsOrigin As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim rngOrigin As Range
    Dim isFIRST_ROW_ODD As Integer
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long

    Set wsOrigin = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDestination = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Set rngOrigin = wsOrigin.Range("A1:A12") 'Change this to suit your needs

    'Below variable stores whether the first row of the rngOrigin variable
    'Is odd or even. Used to know which column the data should be move to
    isFIRST_ROW_ODD = rngOrigin.Rows(1).Row Mod 2

    For Each cel In rngOrigin

        If cel.Row Mod 2 = isFIRST_ROW_ODD Then
        nLastRow = wsDestination.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wsDestination.Cells(nLastRow, 1) = cel.Value
        Else
            wsDestination.Cells(nLastRow, 2) = cel.Value
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfect thanks! If i'm looking to delete the inbetween rows through a seperate macro would I be able to use the same type of code? but reverse it just to delete?

Comment: @Paula, could you clarify which rows represent the 'inbetween' rows that you'd like to delete?

Comment: @Paula I'm leaving another answer below with details on how to delete alternating rows.

Answer (score 1):

[NOTE]To answer a follow up question in the comments regarding deleting alternate rows:

To delete alternating rows, I prefer starting at the bottom of the dataset and working my way upwards. Doing so prevents shifts in the worksheets (due to the deletions) to impact the loop. First, find the last row to be deleted, then loop backwards, stepping by an increment of 2.

```
Sub DeleteAlternateRows()
    Dim nLastRow As Long

    nLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If nLastRow Mod 2 = 0 Then
        nLastRow = nLastRow - 1
    End If

    For i = nLastRow To 1 Step -2
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That does what I'm looking for the only problem is its deleting the wrong alternate ones...I tried swapping it to For i = nLastRow To 1 Step -1 but that just deletes everything :S

Comment: @Paula We definitely don't want to delete everything, LOL! The `Step` part of the `Loop` indicates the size of the increment. `Step - 2` tells our code to move to every OTHER row, not every row. We need to tell our code which row (at the bottom) to start with. Do we have any details upfront about which rows will be deleted (for example, is it every ODD or EVEN row; or do the rows contain a unique identifier or data type)? Using this info, we can build a more robust subroutine.

Comment: nopes definately dont want that lol... o right that explains why it wasnt working with the -1 silly me and it would be every ODD row I would need deleted

Comment: @Paula I just edited my code in the answer above. Now, the code identifies the last row in the data set. It next tests whether the last row is an even or odd row. If it's even, it decrements by one (to move to an odd row), then starts the loop. Let me know if all is well.

Comment: you are a complete legend! Thankyou so much it works perfect and will save me absolutly hours in sorting through this information